# How to use Xquery in Javascript to build an application

Tags: javascript, xml, xquery

How to use Xquery in Javascript to build an application
Must have to use xml database.

Comment: you want to query your db over the network from your client app? Or using a server intermediate?

Comment: I want to combine xquery  and javascript to build an app. Local or network are ok

Comment: try this : http://xqib.org

Answer (score 0):

You could use MarkLogic. In version 8, which came out earlier this year, you can run server side JavaScript, it users the V8 engine. You can also use Xquery as the server side language.

So you could write some parts in xquery and other parts in JavaScript. MarkLogic is also free to develop with. MarkLogic is a document store that has a triple index. So it fits the requirement of being able to store xml. It can also store JSON and many other types.

http://developer.marklogic.com